# Table view cell not showing in table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to get my cells to show in tableView. I searched for questions here but none could help. The table loads fine and I get no errors regarding the tableView. Is there something I'm missing?

-I've double-checked the reuse identifier, they are the same

-I removed and readied the outlets

Here is my UITableViewController class:

```swift
class DrawerViewController: UITableViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var drawerTable: UITableView!

    var currentCell = [DrawerModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addGradientToView(view: drawerTable)

        let temp2Model = DrawerModel()

        temp2Model.item = "Profile"
        temp2Model.icon = "loginbackground2.jpg"

        currentCell.append(temp2Model)

        drawerTable.delegate = self
        drawerTable.dataSource = self
        //self.drawerTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
        //self.drawerTable.reloadData()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = drawerTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "drawerCell", for: indexPath) as! DrawerTableViewCell

        let tempModel: DrawerModel

        tempModel = currentCell[indexPath.row]

        cell.thisLabel.text = tempModel.item

        print("test1" + tempModel.item! as Any)

        let currentImage = UIImage(named: "loginbackground2.jpg")
        cell.thisImage = UIImageView(image: currentImage)

        return cell
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("it ran")

        return currentCell.count
    }

    func addGradientToView(view: UITableView)
    {
        //gradient layer
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        //define colors
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.init(rgb: 0x4b0082).cgColor, UIColor.init(rgb: 0xfa8072).cgColor]

        //define locations of colors as NSNumbers in range from 0.0 to 1.0
        //if locations not provided the colors will spread evenly
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.8]

        //define frame
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds

        //insert the gradient layer to the view layer
        view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Here is my UITableViewCell class:

```swift
class DrawerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var thisImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thisLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Comment: When "it ran" is displayed, you set a break point and the count was positive, right?

Comment: Why have you commented `.reloadData()`  out?? You have to load the data somewhere

Comment: Instead of inheriting from UITableViewContoller, inherit from UIViewController and connect drawertable in storyboard.

Comment: @johnelemans yes, it was positive

Comment: @Barns I saw on one of the posts that it was unnecessary but I'll uncomment it.

Comment: can you comment   addGradientToView(view: drawerTable) and run 
 ??

Comment: @Kamran it is embedded into a container in a UIViewController that I am using as a drawer or root view for navigation so I can't inherit it from the UIViewController

Comment: @Sh_Khan alright I will

Comment: @Barns It worked :) Thank you, please put this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @RobinOlisa There should not be any issue even if you are embedding in some other ViewController. My concern was a UITableViewController itself has a tableView but you are adding another tableView so using two tableView's could be the possible issue. If you want to inherit it from UITableViewController then remove drawerTable and use the provided tableView.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using `UITableViewController` (in your case `DrawerViewController`) it already have a `tableView` property embedded, which have a `delegate` and `dataSource` set to controller.

So when in your case next lines are redundant

```
drawerTable.delegate = self
drawerTable.dataSource = self
```

To fix just call `tableView.reload()` after `currentCell.append(temp2Model)`